# Create multiple columns with Pandas .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have two pandas DataFrames, both containing the same categories but different 'id' columns. In order to illustrate, the first table looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': list(np.arange(1, 12)),
    'category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'weight': list(np.random.randint(1, 5, 11))
})

df['weight_sum'] = df.groupby('category')['weight'].transform('sum')
df['p'] = df['weight'] / df['weight_sum']

Output:

id  category    weight  weight_sum  p
0   1   a   4   14  0.285714
1   2   a   4   14  0.285714
2   3   a   2   14  0.142857
3   4   a   4   14  0.285714
4   5   b   4   8   0.500000
5   6   b   4   8   0.500000
6   7   c   3   15  0.200000
7   8   c   4   15  0.266667
8   9   c   2   15  0.133333
9   10  c   4   15  0.266667
10  11  c   2   15  0.133333
```

The second contains only 'id' and 'category'.

What I'm trying to do is to create a **third DataFrame**, that would have inherit the `id` of the second DataFrame, plus three new columns for the `ids` of the first DataFrame - each should be selected based on the `p` column, which represents its weight within that category.

I've tried multiple solutions and was thinking of applying `np.random.choice` and .apply(), but couldn't figure out a way to make that work.

**EDIT**:

The desired output would be something like:

```
user_id id_1    id_2    id_3
0   2   3   1   2
1   3   2   2   3
2   4   1   3   1
```

With each `id` being selected based on the its probability and respective `category` (both DataFrames have this column), and the same not showing up more than once for the same `user_id`.

[Desired DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjOze.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to select random IDs of the same category with weighted probabilities. For this you can construct a helper dataframe (dfg) and use `apply`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.random.randint(1, 12, size=11),
    'category': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']})

dfg = df.groupby('category').agg(list)

df3 = df2.join(df2['category']
               .apply(lambda r: pd.Series(np.random.choice(dfg.loc[r, 'id'],
                                                           p=dfg.loc[r, 'p'],
                                                           size=3)))
               .add_prefix('id_')
               )
```

Output:

```
    id category  id_0  id_1  id_2
0   11        a     2     3     3
1   10        a     2     3     1
2    4        a     1     2     3
3    7        a     2     1     4
4    5        b     6     5     5
5   10        b     6     5     6
6    8        c     9     8     8
7   11        c     7     8     7
8   11        c    10     8     8
9    4        c     9    10    10
10   1        c    11    11     9
```